# Humorous SF Novel About Cartoon Animal Looking Aliens That Go To Disneyland

Tags: story-identification, aliens, humor

Looking for a humorous science fiction novel about some humorous aliens that look like cartoon animals. They ultimately go public, but before that they visit Disneyland and are stopped by security who assume they are mascot characters for some competitor. However, after a quick X-Ray it is soon realized they are in fact aliens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Myles

Answer (score 3):

Sorry!

I don't know why it took me so long to find the answer. Google Search is not what it used to be! The answer, in case anyone beside me is curious, is Alan Dean Foster's Quozl. Thanks to all who read!